# Gradient triangles

Tags: html, css

I know how to make a triangle with css, but a gradient triangle?

I got this far:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 60px solid transparent;
  border-right: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid black;
}

.triangle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use clip-path to create the triangle:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 100px;
  height:86.6px; /* 0.866 * Width in order to have an equilateral triangle [0.866 = (sqrt(3)/2)] */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, black, blue);
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```